# A fair dice is rolled 3 times. What is the probability that the sum of numbers in the 3 throws is less than 6?

Tags: probability

Is my answer correct

My approach = 9/6*6*6 as the possibilities are

111

112

113

121

122

211

212

221

311

Comment: What about $131$?

Comment: You are not accounting for the different permutations for these numbers. For example, 121 which adds up to 4 can also be 211 and 112.

Comment: Rather than manually listing everything out (*which can easily lead to mistakes and forgotten cases, as above*), it is better to have a strategic approach.  Since each die roll is at least 1, this becomes a question of "I want to distribute less than or equal to two extra pips three spaces, how many ways can I do that?"  This can be solved with stars-and-bars if you like or you can come up with a more direct description, but will result in a value of $\binom{4+2-1}{4-1}=10$

Comment: @Sam the OP did account for the different orderings.  Notice, each of $121,211,112$ all appear in the above list.

Comment: But the same has not been done for 113, 212 and 311

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of gathering the comments into an answer:

Your work would be right, but you've forgotten one case, which is **131**. If you change the 9 in your numerator to 10, you'll have the right answer.

A good follow-up question would be: how does one defend against this kind of error? As JMoravitz suggests, you'd do well to take a systematic approach of some sort. One easy way is to exhaust every possibility in a certain ordering (such as largest to smallest), then explore every possible reordering of those possibilities. Here, that would look like:

111

211

221

311

which could be expanded out to:

111

211 / 121 / 112

221 / 212 / 122

311 / **131** / 113

This would work well for small examples, and would have prevented you from neglecting the 131 example that was missing in your answer. It also helps to defend against repeated items in your list by providing a coherent grouping.

The downside of that approach, though, is that it scales *terribly* with larger problems. If you had changed the "less than 6" in the problem statement to "less than 10," then the approach of listing every possibility would be much more challenging and with higher potential for error. As a general principle, it's good to skip actual listing and counting when you can in favor of combinatorial approaches such as the "stars and bars" approach that JMoravitz suggested. Of course, we shouldn't pretend that those approaches don't have their own plentiful risks of mistakes, because they do.

For a problem of this small scope, I would personally recommend a direct counting approach such as you have done, but others may make a different recommendation. Combinatorics are just fancy counting; ultimately, it's best to both have fancy counting tools *and* to know when you may not need them.

Answer (score 0):

Possible triples : (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,2),(1,1,3) and there rearrangement
 $$1.{3!  \over 3!}+3.{3! \over  2!}=10$$
So probability $ = {10 \over 6^3}$

Or

Take a look at expression $$(x+x^2+x^3)^3=x^3[(1+x)+x^2]^3$$ or
$$x^3[(1+x)^3+x^6+3x^2(x+1)(x^2+x+1)]=x^3[x^3+1+3x^2+3x+x^6+3x^2+....]$$

$x^3$ is common so we need sum coefficients of $x^k$ where k=0,1,2 which is $1+3+3+3=10$.